# How to get Error from different pallet in test?

Tags: testing

In tests we use following statement to check error:

```rust
   assert_noop!(
            ProfileValidation::add_citizen(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), content.clone()),
            Error::<Test>::NoMoreUpdates
    );
```

But how to get error from another coupled pallet.

```rust
OtherCoupledPallet::Error::<Test>::EvidencePeriodNotOver
 // or 
<other_coupled_pallet::Pallet<mock::Test> as TryCollect>::Error::EvidencePeriodNotOver
```

It doesn't work

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really easy.

Check this test. https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/12466db6d4a8d19b2d16461af05b7f155362223b/pallet/deposit/src/tests.rs#L237-L268

This will use the current pallet's `Error`:

```rs
assert_noop!(
    Deposit::lock(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), UNIT, 1),
    <Error<Runtime>>::ExceedMaxDeposits
);
```

And if you want to use an `Error` from other (e.g. `pallet_balances`) pallet, simply write:

```rs
assert_noop!(
    Deposit::lock(RuntimeOrigin::signed(2), 2_001 * UNIT, 1),
    <pallet_balances::Error<Runtime>>::InsufficientBalance
);
```

To use this, make sure you have `impl other_pallet::Config for mock::Runtime {}`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the error from another coupled pallet in a test, you can use the following syntax:

```rust
assert_err!(
    OtherCoupledPallet::some_function(),
    "Expected error message"
);
```

Replace `OtherCoupledPallet::some_function()` with the actual function call you are testing in the other coupled pallet. Make sure to include any required parameters for the function.

In the error message, replace `"Expected error message"` with the specific error message you are expecting. This should be the exact error message that you anticipate the function to produce.

By using `assert_err!`, you can verify that the function call results in an error with the expected error message. If the error message does not match, the assertion will fail, indicating a test failure.

Remember to import the necessary macros at the beginning of your test file:

```rust
use frame_support::assert_err;
```

Including this code in your test should help you check for errors from another coupled pallet.